# Array of complex numbers in PyopenCL

Tags: python, numpy, opencl, algebra, pyopencl

I've been working on a new problem with PyopenCl in which i have to deal with complex numbers. More accurately, it would be really handy to use a 2D numpy array with complex numbers inside. 
Something like: 
np_array[np_array[C_number, C_number, ..], np_array[C_number, C_number, ..], ...]

Then for the results i would need a simple 1D numpy array of complex numbers.

I've also noticed that pyopencl sees a numpy complex number as a float2, for which i use a float16 for my data data array since I have around 8 numbers to deal with.

To work out the basic operations I've built a simple program.
I've worked out building the initials arrays and sending them to the kernel but the results and different from what i expected. I guess it has something to do with the thread's ID but i can't seem to figure it out.

The code i'm using is the following.

```
import pyopencl as cl
import numpy as np

ctx = cl.create_some_context()
queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)
MF = cl.mem_flags

M = 3

zero = np.complex64(0.0)

X1_h = np.array([1 + 1j*2, 2 + 1j*3, 3 + 1j*4]).astype(np.complex64)
X2_h = np.array([1 + 1j*2, 2 + 1j*3, 3 + 1j*4]).astype(np.complex64)
X3_h = np.array([1 + 1j*2, 2 + 1j*3, 3 + 1j*4]).astype(np.complex64)
Y1_h = np.array([4 + 1j*5, 5 + 1j*6, 6 + 1j*7]).astype(np.complex64)
Y2_h = np.array([4 + 1j*5, 5 + 1j*6, 6 + 1j*7]).astype(np.complex64)
Y3_h = np.array([4 + 1j*5, 5 + 1j*6, 6 + 1j*7]).astype(np.complex64)
aux_h = np.complex64(1 + 1j*1)
RES_h = np.empty_like(X1_h)

dados_h = []
for i in range(3):
     dados_h.append(np.array([X1_h[i], X2_h[i], X3_h[i], Y1_h[i], Y2_h[i], Y3_h[i]]).astype(np.complex64))
dados_h = np.array(dados_h).astype(np.complex64)

print dados_h

aux_d = cl.Buffer(ctx, MF.READ_WRITE | MF.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=aux_h)
dados_d = cl.Buffer(ctx, MF.READ_WRITE | MF.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=dados_h)
RES_d = cl.Buffer(ctx, MF.READ_WRITE | MF.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf = RES_h)

Source = """
__kernel void soma(__global float2 *aux, __global float16 *dados, __global float2 *res){
const int gid_x = get_global_id(0);
const int gid_y = get_global_id(1);
res[gid_x].x = dados[gid_y].s0;
res[gid_x].y = dados[gid_y].s1;
}
"""
prg = cl.Program(ctx, Source).build()

completeEvent = prg.soma(queue, (M,), None, aux_d, dados_d, RES_d)
completeEvent.wait()

cl.enqueue_copy(queue, RES_h, RES_d)
print "GPU"
print RES_h
```

The output I'm getting is the following:

```
[[ 1.+2.j  1.+2.j  1.+2.j  4.+5.j  4.+5.j  4.+5.j]
[ 2.+3.j  2.+3.j  2.+3.j  5.+6.j  5.+6.j  5.+6.j]
[ 3.+4.j  3.+4.j  3.+4.j  6.+7.j  6.+7.j  6.+7.j]]
GPU
[ 1.+2.j  1.+2.j  1.+2.j]
```

My expected output is:

```
[ 1.+2.j  2.+3.j  3.+4.j]
```

I can't understand how I'm getting that result. As said, i believe it to be something related to the thread IDs but i can't figure it out. If i use gid_x instead of gid_y on the right part of the red[gid_x] = ... I get the following

```
[ 1.+2.j  2.+3.j  6.+7.j]
```

Can anyone give me some insight in what I'm doing wrong, please?

Comment: If you plan to have  2D grid, that code will have horrible race conditions, because multiple work items will have the same X coordinate and therefore they will write to the same memory location.

Comment: I didn't explain what i wanted to do quite well and I was a bit confused on what i was actually doing but i didn't even think of that. Thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're launching a 1D kernel, so `get_global_id(1)` will always return `0`. This explains why your kernel simply copies the first element of the `dados` array into each element of the output.

Using a `float16` to represent one 'row' of your input only works if you actually have 8 complex numbers per row. In your example you only have 6, which is why you don't quite get the correct results when copying from `dados[gid_x]`.

To allow your code to deal with an arbitrary row size, simply pass the width in as a parameter, and then compute the linear index manually:

```
__kernel void soma(__global float2 *aux,
                   __global float2 *dados,
                   __global float2 *res,
                   int rowWidth){
  const int gid_x = get_global_id(0);
  res[gid_x] = dados[gid_x*rowWidth];
}
```

and then pass the row-width as an extra argument when you launch the kernel:

```
# Pass your actual row-width instead of 6!
completeEvent = prg.soma(queue, (M,), None, aux_d, dados_d, RES_d, np.int32(6))
```